# Replacing Request/Response Body in asp.net core middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, request, httpcontext, asp.net-core-middleware

I want to replace the request/response body in my middleware. Suppose if client sends *Hello*, I want to change it to *Hola* and similarly with response. I found the code that works but not to my requirement. My question is why this works and the other do not. It is actually the same code.

**Working Code**

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
       {
            var request = context.Request;
            var stream = request.Body;// currently holds the original stream                    
            var originalReader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var originalContent = await originalReader.ReadToEndAsync();
            var notModified = true;
            try
            {

                if (originalContent != null)
                {
                    //Master is some model name
                    var modifiedData = new Master() { Id = "Changed in Middleware", Email = "Changed" };
                    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(modifiedData);
                    //json variable is just a string here
                    //modified stream
                    var requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
                    stream = new MemoryStream(requestData);
                    notModified = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            if (notModified)
            {
                //putting original data
                var requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(originalContent);
                stream = new MemoryStream(requestData);
            }

            request.Body = stream;
            
            await next(context);
        }
```

**Not working Code But My Requirement**

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
       {
            var request = context.Request;
            var stream = request.Body;// currently holds the original stream                    
            var originalReader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var originalContent = await originalReader.ReadToEndAsync();
            var notModified = true;
            try
            {

                if (originalContent != null)
                {
                    var json = "This is just a string as deserializing returns string";
                    //modified stream
                    var requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
                    stream = new MemoryStream(requestData);
                    notModified = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            if (notModified)
            {
                //putting original data
                var requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(originalContent);
                stream = new MemoryStream(requestData);
            }

            request.Body = stream;
            
            await next(context);
        }
```

So the **working code** pass on the changes to the controller, and has value *Id ="Changed in middlware"* and *Email = "changed"* but the **not working code** doesnt pass anything ... in the controller, argument has null and not the *"This is just a string as deserializing returns string"* value. I know this is not some magic happening. Am i missing something?

Comment: Are you sure that `originalContent` has data?

Comment: @NicolaBiada yes in the debugger i can easily see what it has...for both object one and string one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert string to jsontype.Try to change your code like this:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
   {
        var request = context.Request;
        var stream = request.Body;// currently holds the original stream                    
        var originalReader = new StreamReader(stream);
        var originalContent = await originalReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        var notModified = true;
        try
        {

            if (originalContent != null)
            {
                var str = "This is just a string as deserializing returns string";
                //convert string to jsontype
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(str);
                //modified stream
                var requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
                stream = new MemoryStream(requestData);
                notModified = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        if (notModified)
        {
            //putting original data
            var requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(originalContent);
            stream = new MemoryStream(requestData);
        }

        request.Body = stream;
        
        await next(context);
    }
```

TestRequestBody Action:

```
public IActionResult TestRequestBody([FromBody] string s)
        {

            return Ok();
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: was stuck for quite sometime ... thank you so much ..
could you tell why we need to serialise though?

Comment: Request body requires json  type data,so you need to serialize it.

Comment: is it same for the response? I tried in the same way, but nothing is showing up at client side. and I also tried to write in to the same response.body object and I couldn't able to overwrite the model data when modelstate is not valid (I'm getting both model data and the custom response I want to return).